# How to compute a cumulative percent on multiple categories in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, business-intelligence

I'd like to compute a line graph showing the running percent between the actuals and open-orders with the forecast.

Here is a sample of my data structure:
[data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldaln.png)

Here is the problem i currently have: [problematic running percent line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzIgp.png)

As you can see, the percent is not cumulative.

Finally, here is the dax expression i'm currently stuck with (tried other formulas, to no avail): [dax expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqhES.png)

Any hint, insight or help is more than welcome!

Comment: So i think i'm not grasping something essential here. I think it's impossible for the percent to cumulate as i'm trying to play with two different measures (which are not really meant to interact in the way i'm looking for). The forecasts has huge spikes, whereas the actuals sometimes barelly follow, therefore leading to the camelback i'm trying to avoid. If someone has expertise on the matter, i'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Can you provide a reproducible example without screenshots? Here is a guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You can include markdown tables if that makes it easier.

Comment: Hey again. So i've found out my problem. I was trying to compute a progression line based on the formula: DIVIDE(cumulative_actuals, cumulative_forecast). Which is wrong! The right answer was DIVIDE(cumulative_actuals, total_forecast_all).